# Airflow Subdag started but tasks within it not starting

Tags: python, airflow

I have a situation and problem in my production airflow. Here it goes :

---

There’s a dag with multiple subdags. when I trigger the dag, sub-dag got triggered and shows as in progress but the tasks inside it are not getting started. shows as blank for long time.

When I try to render the pod spec, this error shows :

```
Error rendering Kubernetes Pod Spec: Parent instance <TaskInstance at 0x7faaa5f48d60> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute ‘dag_model’ cannot proceed (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/bhk3)
```

```
Apache Airflow : 2.2.3
python 3.x
```

Comment: It seems you try to access `dag_model` outside the airflow db session, can you add a part of your dag (where you trigger a sub dag), and the code of a sub dag?

Comment: @HusseinAwala Thanks for responding. Here is the code you asked for :

Comment: @HusseinAwala Thanks for responding. Here is the code you asked for :   `code` dag code: args = {
    'owner': 'myself',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    'provide_context': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'on_failure_callback': task_fail_slack_alert
}DAG_NAME = 'my dag process'

# Define DAG properties
dag = DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_NAME,
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    tags=['My Dag']
)  `code`

Comment: @HusseinAwala cant format this in comment section. let me know if you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, sometimes this happens to me too. Maybe it is an Airflow bug, I don't know.

What I do instead is force the Subdag to trigger manually:

[image: Manually trigger subdag]

After I do this once, the next DAG execution will run as expected.

Edit:

After some research, I found out this DAG parameter might be related **is_paused_upon_creation**, once it is set to **false** it should start the Subdag if this is the first time it ever runs.

Look at [the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html) for more info